# How to get maximum horizontal scroll distance in an EditText

Tags: android, text, scroll, android-edittext, horizontal-scrolling

I'm having a bit of difficulty getting a rather simple app I'm working on to function properly. The way it's set up is there are two sliding drawer style menus on either side of the screen and a multiline EditText in the center. The problem I'm having is the EditText has to have horizontal scrolling and that doesn't work because the draws open before the text scrolls. I was able to fix this for the left menu because android has a function to get the horizontal displacement from the left:

```
View.getScrollX();
```

and when that's equal to 0 I can enable the left menu. and that works fine. I've been wondering how to do this for the right side because I can't get the maximum scroll distance, and on top of that, the text size can change on demand and I'm not using a set width font - so it can't just be calculated. Thanks for any help.